# SSIS: failed to lock variable [with full path]

Tags: ssis

I have created an SSIS package that is supposed to create a file and FTP it, but I'm having problems.

- Using a variable `@User:FilePath` with an expression to create a dynamic file name with date parts in it for export
  [image: screenshot1]
  Expression:

  ```
  "C:\\WFSDEV_WSD_SHIP_FROM_STORE_" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",@[System::StartTime]) + 
  RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",@[System::StartTime]) ,2) + 
  RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",@[System::StartTime]),2) +
  RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("hh",@[System::StartTime]),2) +
  RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",@[System::StartTime]),2) +
  RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("ss",@[System::StartTime]),2) +
  ".VD01"
  ```
- `Data Flow` Task has `OLE DB Source` and `Flat File Destination`. The latter using the variable (but 'connectionstring' still fills in with the evaluated value)

[image: screenshot2]

Now, in the FTP Task, I have add an expression as the variable pointing to '`LocalPath'`, and it always fills in the '`LocalPath`' with the evaluated value.
[image]

So, here's the error I keep getting telling me the 'variable' cannot be locked, but it's the actual VALUE not the variable name.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In further research, I found that using an '`Expression Task`' and selecting my single variable as the FIRST TASK in the list solved the problem. I'm guessing it handles creation of the variable first.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the value of `IsLocalPathVariable` property of FTP Task to `False`.
If this doesn't work, then create another variable with the same expression and call this new variable in your FTP task `LocalPath` expression.

Comment: I wound up making another variable with the same expression and it works. It would be great to figure out how to use a single variable for multiple steps as modifying one of the variables without modifying the other will break it.

Comment: You could utilize precedence constraints to make sure that one component is done with a variable before having the next component use it to avoid lockouts like this. Any parallel processing components that uses the same variable may lead to variable not being available whenever another component request it.

Comment: EDIT: In further research, I found that using an 'Expression Task' and selecting my single variable as the FIRST TASK in the list solved the problem. I'm guessing it handles creation of the variable first.

Comment: By creating the 'Expression Task', you are setting the value of the variable once and establishing a precedence constraint; As opposed to how you were calculating the value of the variable in two different containers before.